# Why does redux form return string instead of the object?

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am trying to access the touched property on my redux form, but for some reason when I print the field props I only the value instead of the object. What am I missing?

```
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';

render() {
  const { fields: { email, phone }, handleSubmit } = this.props;
  console.log(email) //prints just the value "email" instead of the field object with the touched method, etc. When I do console.log(email.touched) I get undefined error.
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
       <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" { ...email } />
       <Field name="phone" component="input" type="number" { ...phone } />     
    </form>
  );


}


export default ReduxFormTest = reduxForm({
  form: 'uniqueForm',
  fields: ['email', 'phone']
})(TestClass);
```

Answer (score 2):

There were breaking changes in redux-forms from v5 to v6. Previously you could do something similar to what you have to access the touched field. If you want to do something similar to see if there are errors on a field, you need to create your own component to pass to redux-form's Field component.

Your custom component

```
const CustomComponent = function(field) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type={field.type}
        {...field.input}
        />
      {field.meta.touched && field.meta.error && <div className='error'>{field.meta.error}</div>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then using it with the Field component

```
<Field name="my-prop" component={CustomComponent} />
```

Also take a look at the migration [guide](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/MigrationGuide.md/), hope this helps!

Comment: This works, only issue is that when I type one character into the input, it goes inactive and I have to click again to continue typing.

Comment: I saw you edited the field.meta.touched line but I didn't add that in yet so the issue is not in that.

Comment: The above problem only happens for the first field I try to type in.

Comment: Would const CustomComponent be defined inside the render method or would I have to put it in its own class?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing `v5` syntax with `v6` syntax. In `v6`, your decorated form component is no longer passed `this.props.fields`. Re-read the migration guide, like @tyler-iguchi said.